# What is the tank size of a honda shadow 750 (2009)?

Tags: honda, motorcycle

I have a Honda Shadow 750 (Aero). I see people saying they fill it up to 3.8 gallons. I can't get even near to that.

When I get to 1.8 the pump stops automatically and with 1.8 I can ride for about 110 miles.

Is there anything wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: Knowing what year of bike you're talking about would help tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

[This website says](http://www.motorcycle-usa.com/24614/Buyers-Guide-Specifications/2009-Honda-Shadow-750-Aero.aspx) it's a 3.7 gallon tank with a 0.9 gallon reserve. I'm thinking you aren't filling it to the top or even near the filler neck. If you have the filler handle nose stuck down in the tank, as soon as the gas covers the snout it's going to click off. Try pulling it out a little bit and filling it some more. If you can see space between the filler neck and the gas level, you can always put some more in. Don't overflow the tank though ... that would make for a dangerous situation.

Comment: Today I got to 2.5 gallons, with fuel valve off, if that makes any difference. The gas level was 3-4 inches to the top. ..

Comment: @Bob ... sounds like you can drop quite a bit more fuel into the tank if you have 3-4" of room left. Don't know that it would be 1.2 gallons difference, though.

Comment: @Bob I always fill the tank to just a few millimeters below either the fill neck or gas cap (when there is no fill neck - not sure how that bike's gas tank looks). On all the bike's I've owned, this usually seems to be 'full'.

Comment: @Paul I did to, today. It actually came out a little bit, and it was a little less than 2.5 gallons, so definitely not 3.7

Comment: @Bob - I'm wondering if you aren't starting from empty? The number I gave you is from Honda. Anyway you look at it, you're putting more in now than when you started.

Comment: @Bob Did you run the tank down to reserve?

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2006 Honda VT750C Aero.  The most fuel than I have ever put in my fuel tank after running the regular tank dry is 2.91 gallons .  Today I ran the tank dry (not the reserve) and filled it with 2.83 gallons.  I switched to reserve at 146 miles according to the trip meter and I filled it with the trip odometer reading 156 miles.   It took 2.83 gallons to fill the tank to the neck.   Keep in mind that my speedometer is approximately 8-10 percent fast.
 One of these times I’m going to run reserve empty and then fill it up to see how much total gas the fuel tank does hold .   According to the manufactures specs it is supposed to hold 3.7 gallons.

Answer (score 0):

I have trouble filling mine to the neck because there is some kind of baffle about 2 inches inside presumably to keep the gas from sloshing.  But i can fill it to the neck, and pause, and the gas slowly goes down as if it were draining through a small opening. Then after about 30 seconds I can squeeze a bit more in. Repeat. Takes me a good ten minutes before I get bored and give up. I got 2.5 gal in mine today.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2015 Honda Shadow Phantom. The other day I rode 193 miles before the fuel light came on. I happened to be right by a gas station. I was able to put 3.1 gallons in. You have to be patient. Pull the nozzle almost out and pump only a few seconds at a time, give the fuel time to settle down and pump a few more. Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2006 vt 750 and I filled up at 141 miles, not yet on reserve, and it took 2.1 gallons to fill, happy chappy